# How to send muliptle lists of hex strings from af unix socket in python

Tags: python, string, list, hex, unix-socket

I am trying to send `multiple` `hex` strings in a list from `AF` unix socket

```
from binascii import unhexlify   
message = [b'8501012a1b0ff5ff',b'8501012a1b000ff']
mess1 = unhexlify(message)
print(mess1)
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: plz provide [mcve]

Comment: from binascii import unhexlify my_list_strings = ['850123ff','850123456'ff]  my_hex = unhexlify(my_list_strings)  print(my_hex).Here i am trying to make a list of strings what i have and i an converting to hex using unhexlify and trying to send these list of hex string from af unix socket to the server

Comment: im experiencing TypeError: argument should be bytes, buffer or ASCII string, not <class 'list'>
when converting list of strings to hex and sending through socket